# Dynamic list with jQuery - checkbox and dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me out, please? I'm using jQuery.
I need to have 5 languages. It is a dynamic list.

Action: Every language has a checkbox, and a dropdown along with it, which is only shown when the checkbox is checked.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mc2Rw/

Comment: Please explain what's the problem? The code is working. It displays the dropdown when check Spanish and hides it when we uncheck the language.

Comment: I just give the example...i need that code dynamically...like it can be placed in php for loop.....with jquery...

Comment: Please stop creating user accounts. :P

Comment: @Allove Then what's the problem? Just write this code on PHP!

Comment: <table>
<?
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{ ?>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="chk[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="chk[<?php echo $i; ?>]" onclick="showd('<?php echo $i; ?>');" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" /></td>
      <td>Language_<?php echo $i; ?></td>
      <td>      
   <select name="level" id="f_level_<?php echo $i; ?>" >
    <option value="None">your level</option>
    <option value="Low">Low</option>
    <option value="Average">Average</option>    
  </select></td>
    </tr>
    <?
}
?>
  </table>

Comment: @Allove your new account is showing a remarkable improvement in wording questions... Now to work on the comments eh?

Comment: @DanielHanly: Since I edited this question... -.-

Comment: @Nyuszika and so the tables have turned... but why did @Allove just claim credit for your work. That's plagiarism right there ;)

Comment: @Allove: Please edit that table code into your question instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

    mysql_select_db('badoo',mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''));    

if($_REQUEST)
{
    $id     = $_REQUEST['q'];
    $query = "select id,language,code from language where id = ".$id;
    $results = mysql_query( $query); 
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results );

    if($rows!='')
    {?>
        <div>
        <label for="lang_<?=$rows['code'];?>" >
          <input name="language[<?=$rows['code'];?>]" id="lang_<?=$rows['code'];?>" checked="checked" value="1" type="checkbox">
          <?=$rows['language'];?>
        </label>
        <select  name="level[<?=$rows['code'];?>]" id="f_level_<?=$rows['code'];?>">
          <option selected="selected" value="">your level</option>
          <option value="Low">Low</option>
          <option value="Average">Average</option>
          <option value="Fluent">Fluent</option>
          <option value="Native">Native</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    return;
}
?>
```

Comment: -1 as I do not see how this is the accepted solution when the OP is asking about dynamically hiding and showing a `<select>` when a checkbox is checked. This code only outputs some `<select>` elements. Where exactly is the JavaScript in this answer?

Comment: You do know that that jQuery **IS** JavaScript, don't you? My question still stands... how is this the accepted solution when there is no JavaScript in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

easier that way :

```
$('#lang_es').click(function(){
    $('#f_level_es').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy, just added some classes, improved the code a bit. Then I just duplicated the HTML, and made the JavaScript work for all checkboxes.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mc2Rw/2/

Answer (score 1):

This PHP (you can paste [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) to test) code:

```
$languages = array('en' => 'English', 'es' => 'Spanish', 'fr' => 'French', 'de' => 'German', 'kl' => 'Klingon');

function selectifyMe($language, $key) {
    echo $html = <<<HTML
<div>
    <label for="lang_$key"><input type="checkbox" name="language[$key]" id="lang_$key" value="1"/>$language</label>
    <select name="level[]" id="f_level_$key">
        <option value="None">your level</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Average">Average</option>
        <option value="Fluent">Fluent</option>
        <option value="Native">Native</option>
    </select>
</div>
HTML;
}
array_walk($languages, 'selectifyMe');
```

produces the HTML in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CHSUV/3/). Might need some tweaking for your layout/CSS classes.

**Edit:** Complete `.php` page example:

```
<?php
$languages = array('en' => 'English', 'es' => 'Spanish', 'fr' => 'French', 'de' => 'German', 'kl' => 'Klingon');

function selectifyMe($language, $key) {
    echo $html = <<<HTML
<div>
    <label for="lang_$key"><input type="checkbox" name="language[$key]" id="lang_$key" value="1"/>$language</label>
    <select name="level[]" id="f_level_$key">
        <option value="None">your level</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Average">Average</option>
        <option value="Fluent">Fluent</option>
        <option value="Native">Native</option>
    </select>
</div>
HTML;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            height:25px;
        }
        label {
            text-align:left;
            width:100px;
            display:inline-block;
            vertical-align:top;
        }
        input {
            margin-right:5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('select').toggle();
            $('input').click(function(event){
                $(this).closest('div').children('select').toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    array_walk($languages, 'selectifyMe');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which js need to be include ?

Comment: I had used jQuery 1.5.2 (you can see this on the jsfiddle demo page). You can either [download it yourself](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js) to host on your server or use the Google API like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Sir,It is not working ..i include every code..... http://jsfiddle.net/mc2Rw/2/ this code also

Comment: It display all the checkbox along with dropdown

Comment: You need to combine the PHP and JavaScript to create the final page. Are you processing the PHP correctly by a web server?

Comment: What exactly is not working. I don't think you are using the code correctly. All you need is the code from my answer and nothing else. Just copy the code from the "complete .php page example" part of my answer and save it to a file called "test.php". Put that file in the root directory of your PHP/Apache (I assume) web server for example ` C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\var\www`.

Comment: You can browse to that page with `http://localhost/test.php`. It should render the 5 checkbox/select element rows and the JavaScript should work as the jQuery library is loaded from Google's CDN.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
div {
    height:25px;
}
label {
    text-align:left;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
input {
    margin-right:5px;
}
</style>
  <script type="text/javascript">

function showCD(str)
{
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //          document.getElementById("newone").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            $('#newone').append(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //          document.getElementById('newone').appendChild(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "123.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
         //$('select').toggle();

        $('input').click(function(event) {
            $(this).closest('div').children('select').toggle();
        });


    });
    //]]> 
</script>

<?php 

    @mysql_select_db('badoo',mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''));   



    $query = "select id,language,code from language  WHERE first=1";
    $results = mysql_query( $query);
    $lang = array();

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(@$results)){
        $lang[$rows['language']] = $rows['code'];
    }

?>

<form action="" method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm" >
  <?php     
    foreach($lang as $key=>$value){ ?>
  <div>
    <label for="lang_<?=$value;?>" >
      <input name="language[<?=$value;?>]" id="lang_<?=$value;?>" value="1" type="checkbox">
      <?=$key;?>
    </label>
    <select style="display: none;" name="level[<?=$value;?>]" id="f_level_<?=$value;?>">
      <option selected="selected" value="">your level</option>
      <option value="Low">Low</option>
      <option value="Average">Average</option>
      <option value="Fluent">Fluent</option>
      <option value="Native">Native</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>

  <input value="submit" name="submit" type="submit">

<!--**********************************************************-->

<br />
<br />
<br />


<?php 

    @mysql_select_db('badoo',mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''));   



    $query = "select id,language,code from language WHERE first=0";
    $results = mysql_query( $query);
    $lang = array();

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(@$results)){
        $lang[$rows['language']] = $rows['code'];
    }

?>


<select  name="level[]" id="f_level" onchange="showCD(this.value)">
      <option selected="selected" value="">language</option>      
<?php     
    $results = mysql_query( $query);


    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(@$results)){
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>" ><?php echo $rows['language'];?></option>
<?php    
    }
    ?>
</select>

<div id="newone"></div>
</form>
```